# Composite Models with INotifyPropertyChanged - PostSharp Delegate Changes from SubModels

Tags: c#, postsharp

First of all, I do use the NotifyPropertyChanged implementation for Change handling and not MVVM implementation.

That said i have the following construct:

```
[NotifyPropertyChanged]
public interface ISpecimen : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string Name { get; }
    IOpticModel Optics { get; }
}

[NotifyPropertyChanged]
public interface IOpticModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string Lens { get; }
    void UpdateOptics(string lens);
}
```

Now I want PostSharp to Notify me that the Specimen Property Optics got changed (or more precise modified) when I Update the Lens of the IOpticModel. How can i achieve that? Is there anything already ready to go or do i need to create a custom Aspect for that?

I did expect something like that to be ready to use but may be just to blind to find it in the Docs.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is currently not supported. This means that you'd need to raise the event manually.

You can submit a feature request at https://postsharp.uservoice.com/.